# Images not loading on wordpress.org site

Tags: images

I have a self-hosted site (via tsohost) and when going on my site via my own wifi - not anyone else's or mobile data - the images don't load. they just come up with the little image symbol and the title of the image.

I've been through loads of steps with my Internet provider and TSOHost and they both said it's not to do with them - but every other site works! Just not mine.

I don't understand the techy side of things - my hosting company did everything for me, I just write the blog posts lol.

Any ideas?

Comment: We need some code to look at.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that :(

Comment: This is a developers' mutual aid Q&A site, maybe https://wordpress.org/support/ will be a better place to find some help with your current issue. Good luck!

Comment: Someone on that site recommended this one :p